# Where is the SQL Server Database Trigger Wizard or Dialog Box?

Tags: sql-server, database

This question is about SQL Server

In the past, I have created a stored procedure that was run on a timely basis by (if I remember correctly) a database trigger.  As I recall, there was a wizard (dialog box with "NEXT" buttons) that I used to set things up to have the stored procedure run automatically.  That was some time ago.  Now when I search for database trigger information online,  I find only information about  -- creating triggers for when a table is updated or modified.  Maybe I am using the wrong terminology and what I am looking for is not a "trigger" at all.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the SQL Server Agent which will run jobs according to a set schedule.  What edition of SQL Server are you using?  It's not available in all of them (like Express).

Comment: You are looking for SQL Server Agent no question, Triggers are nothing to do with schedulled automation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a trigger what you are looking for.
You need to find sql server agent in sql server managment studio, create a new job, add a step, select database and use the command `EXEC yourSpName` to run the stored procedure.
Then in the schedule you can set when you want to run it.

Comment: `sp_name` doesn't exist in SQL Server.  Are you thinking MySQL?

Comment: Of sp_name desen't exist, you have to replace with the name of the stored spocedure 'EXEC name'

Comment: @Allesandro Ah, my apologies.  It's just that `sp_name` does exist in other platforms and it was unclear to me that you were suggesting a replacement.  If you do a quick edit I'll remove my downvote.  Maybe make it say `EXEC my_sp` or something so it's more clear?

Comment: @squillman No problem, you are right, it could be misleading. I changed it